# Android App crashing using getWritableDatabase

Tags: android, database, sqlite, crash

Alright, so I have been searching this question and I have found a couple of answers that I have tried to no success. I noticed that if I comment out getWritableDatabase the app doesn't crash but it does not complete the operation I want.

I also referenced this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKM&index=31&list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E) to help me create the classes

Here is my SQLHelper Class:

```
package com.example.amasio.testapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Amasio on 11/9/15.
 */
public class DatabaseController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "BANNER ID";
    public static final String COL_3 = "FIRST NAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "LAST NAME";
    public static final String COL_5 = "GPA";
    public static final String COL_6 = "MAJOR";

    public DatabaseController(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "FIRST NAME TEXT, LAST NAME TEXT, GPA REAL, MAJOR TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertStudent(int bannerId, String firstName, String lastName, double gpa, String major){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_2, bannerId);
        cv.put(COL_3, firstName);
        cv.put(COL_4, lastName);
        cv.put(COL_5, gpa);
        cv.put(COL_6, major);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Activity:

```
package com.example.amasio.testapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseController studentDb;
    Student s;
    EditText bannerIdText;
    EditText firstNameText;
    EditText lastNameText;
    //add email EditText
    EditText gpaText;
    Spinner majorSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Sign Up");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        bannerIdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bannerId);
        firstNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        gpaText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gpa);
        majorSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.major);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.college_majors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        majorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onRegisterClicked(View v){

        int banner = Integer.parseInt(bannerIdText.getText().toString());
        double gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaText.getText().toString());
        String majorValue = majorSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        studentDb = new DatabaseController(this);
        boolean inserted = studentDb.insertStudent(banner, firstNameText.getText().toString(),
                lastNameText.getText().toString(), gpa, majorValue);

        if(inserted){
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Log:

```
11-10 00:24:56.781 21455-21455/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.amasio.testapplication, PID: 21455
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4298)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4293)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Student(ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRST NAME TEXT, LAST NAME TEXT, GPA REAL, MAJOR TEXT);
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: #################################################################
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime:  (near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Student(ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRST NAME TEXT, LAST NAME TEXT, GPA REAL, MAJOR TEXT);)
11-10 00:24:56.791 21455-21455/? E/AndroidRuntime: #################################################################
```

EDIT: I have made a couple of changes to the classes.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "FIRST_NAME TEXT, LAST_NAME TEXT, GPA DOUBLE, MAJOR TEXT);");

}
```

This is in the Activity:

```
public void onRegisterClicked(View v){

        int banner = Integer.parseInt(bannerIdText.getText().toString());
        double gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaText.getText().toString());
        String majorValue = majorSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        studentDb = new DatabaseController(this);
        boolean inserted = studentDb.insertStudent(banner, firstNameText.getText().toString(),
                lastNameText.getText().toString(), gpa, majorValue);

        if(inserted){
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
11-10 12:06:04.631 31358-31393/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 29
11-10 12:06:05.291 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "NAME": syntax error
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting FIRST NAME=mike LAST NAME=page BANNER ID=950266678 MAJOR=Computer Science GPA=3.88
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "NAME": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Student(FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,BANNER ID,MAJOR,GPA) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: #################################################################
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase:  (near "NAME": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Student(FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,BANNER ID,MAJOR,GPA) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?))
11-10 12:06:05.301 29884-29884/? E/SQLiteDatabase: #################################################################
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: Hello mapage2 Is my answer is working for you?

Comment: @Amsheer I'm going to try it soon. I really appreciate your input. I hope I can fix that -1 problem going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "FIRST NAME TEXT, LAST NAME TEXT, GPA REAL, MAJOR TEXT);");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "FIRST_NAME TEXT, LAST_NAME TEXT, GPA_REAL, MAJOR TEXT);");
```

Note : Remove the space from the column names. This is one issue. If it not solved let me know.

Comment: I don't not know why that happened. I tried to +1 but my app said I need more reputation. Next thing I know it says -1. Sorry!

Comment: There are still syntax errors left, such as missing `PRIMARY KEY` before `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Answer (score -1):

I have read your logcat and i find out a syntax error near

"AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Student(ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, BANNER ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRST NAME TEXT, LAST NAME TEXT, GPA REAL, MAJOR TEXT);)

there are spaces in your attribute names remove those or add _ instead of spaces

Comment: Ignore the previous comment just fixed it! Thanks